# Set the range of pairwise distance and cosine similarity between 0 and 1

Tags: pytorch, lstm, cosine-similarity, siamese-network, pairwise-distance

I write a BiLSTM-Siamese Network to measure the string similarities using pairwise distance and cosine similarities with the detail as follows:

```
class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, dropout, weight_matrix, vocabs, similarity_measure):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()        
        self.lstm_network = BiLSTM(num_layers, weight_matrix, vocabs)
        self.fc_drop = nn.Dropout(p = dropout)
        self.similarity_measure = similarity_measure
        if self.similarity_measure == 'euclidean_distance':
            self.sm = nn.PairwiseDistance(p=2)
        else:
            self.sm = nn.functional.cosine_similarity
        
    def forward(self, input1, input2):
        output1 = self.lstm_network(input1)
        output2 = self.lstm_network(input2)
        
        out1 = self.fc_drop(output1)
        out2 = self.fc_drop(output2)
        
        x = self.sm(out1, out2)
        if self.similarity_measure == 'euclidean_distance':
            x = 1-x  # The larger the x value is, the more similar the strings are.      
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)

        return x
```

I used the torch.sigmoid to make the similarity degree between 0 and 1. However, the sigmoid makes the same string pair’s similarities, not 1. Hence, I need to know how to make the range of the similarity degree in the range 0-1 using the pairwise distance and cosine similarity. 0 if the string pairs are dissimilar and 1 if the string pairs are similar. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to solve your problems. For the `cosine similariry` case, the output should already been in range `[-1,1]`, now you can choose to clip all the values that is smaller than `0` to be `0` (**recommended**), like:

```
x = torch.clamp(x, 0, 1)
```

or scale them to be in range `[0,1]` (**not rcommended**):

```
x = (x + 1)/2
```

For the case of `euclidian distance`, your approach is right. If you want the threshold "harder", consider:

```
x = torch.sigmoid(alpha * x) ## with alpha > 1 make the result more aggresive toward 0 and 1
```

Or because `x` being the distance, which make `x >= 0` in all case, you can use any exponential function to calculate similarity, for example:

```
x = self.sm(out1, out2)
x = torch.exp( - alpha * x) ## alpha > 0
```

A thing to note is that you should not use `sigmoid` in the `cosine similarity` case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The torch.clamp for the cosine similarity does help to solve the problem. However, for Euclidean distance, the result of the same string pairs using the torch.sigmoid(alpha * x) is 0.5. Meanwhile, torch.exp( - alpha * x ) returns 1, but the problem is that the equation returns high similarities for dissimilar pairs and low similarities for similar pairs. Is it okay to scale the out1 and out2 in the range [0,1] then measure the pairwise distance and normalize it by x = 1/(1+x)?

Comment: `but the problem is that the equation returns high similarities for dissimilar pairs and low similarities for similar pairs` how can this be? `scale the out1 and out2 in the range [0,1] then measure the pairwise distance and normalize it by x = 1/(1+x)` the best way is to try it to see if your model learn good representation. But I think you should not normalize `out1` and `out2` as it will make their distance small then `x = 1/(1+x)` will still be large for dissimilar pair.

Comment: Oh sorry. The `x = torch.exp( - alpha * x)` works fine. Thank you for your help. :) @Minh Nguyen Hoang